# New Route not working on IIS 7.5

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, routes, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been developing an MVC application locally (IIS Express) and deploing to IIS 7.5 periodically in order to test.

I have just added a new named Route to my Global.asax.cs file:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "MyCustomRoute", // Route name
            "{documentID}/{year}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Documents", action = "CurrentVersion", year = DateTime.Now.Year }, // Parameter defaults
            new { documentID = @".*\d+.*" } // Regex matches only where documentID contains numerical values.
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Documents", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I have set up a Html.RouteLink using "MyCustomRoute" and all works well on my local machine.
However, when I run this on the Web Server, Html.RouteLink is generating an empty link. In addition, if i enter the URL directly into the browser, it gives a 404.

It seems as if the Route has not registered. What am I missing?

Comment: Show us the route.  Also, sometimes the order in which you list the route is important.  Put your new route before the default route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible for us to debug your route without seeing the code, and if you use the right tools, it will be very easy for you to see what's going on and what is being matched.

Phil Haack built an excellent open source tool called **RouteDebugger**.  You can [get it through NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger) and read about how to use it at http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx .  A more robust version of this project is available as [**RouteMagic** and is at Codeplex](http://routemagic.codeplex.com/) and [git](https://github.com/Haacked/RouteMagic).    Details at [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Based on your regex, you're documentID is not being matched due to greediness.  `.*` will match everything, so you it will never have the opportunity to match `\d+`, because the preceding pattern will cannibalize all matches.  You can read about regex greediness and laziness at http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html .

**UPDATE 2**

Regexes are probably the thing I'm worst at programming, and the only reason I recognized that issue is because I am so bad at them that I've run into the same issue about a million times.  That being said, I **think** `@"(.*?)(\d+?)(.*?)"` will do the trick.  It should work without any of the parentheses as well (like `@".*?\d+?.*?"`), but I like to keep them in there for readability (mostly because I'm so bad at them).

Comment: Hi, I have added my Routes, but surely if it is working locally then it is not a problem with the Routes themselves? It just seems as though my new Route is not being registered.

Comment: @james, Are you sure that you redeployed the assembly for the web project after the latest change?

Comment: I did a File System deploy from VS2010, deleting everything on the Server prior to publish. It is my custom route which fails, the default routing is functioning as normal.

Comment: Can you give an example of a particular request that fails?

Comment: If I go to mytestsite.com/documentID or mytestsite.com/documentID/2012 for example. Both URLs should return a view but seem to be unrecognised.

Comment: What is an example of a document ID?  I believe that you're regex may be excluding you're actual request due to greediness, but I cannot confirm this without a concrete example

Comment: Brilliant, thats it! The specific documentID I was using in my test data happend to not contain a numeric value. So the route was failing. Can't beleive that I missed it. Thanks for the help smartcaveman. Incidentally, do you have a better regex in mind? Basically my documentIDs always (should!) contain numerical some numerical values.